# How should i hightlight any link on mouseover in  my page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight all the links in my website when mouse over events happen on them.

I don't want to write the `onmouseover` attribute in every link I create and there should be some place where I can declare this highlight effect globally.

How should i do this ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by highlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS. You should use external file if you wnat to make it same for you whole site.

```
a:hover 
{
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

You may use class or something else. Such as JS.
But I think the above example would be OK if you want to make it for all links.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simply through CSS.

```
<style="text/css"><!--
  a, a:visited { color:#AA0000; text-decoration:none; }
  a:hover { color:#00AA00; text-decoration:underlined; }
--></style>

<a href="URLhere">Link1</a><br />
<a href="URLhere">Link2</a><br />
```

Comment: +1 - I was too focused on javascript, your solution is so much simpler.

Comment: haha no problem! at times I'm too focused on doing things with JS too =D

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work fairly well:

```
a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do minimal styling on links on events like 'hover', you don't need JS at all:

```
a { color:blue; }
a:hover { color:red; }
```

If you're going beyond that and possibly adding balloon style hovers you'll most likely need to rely on Javascript, it might help clarifying exactly what you mean by highlight.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is either to write your own selector, or use a selector function in something like jQuery.

That way you can just do a mouseover function on any `a` element on the webpage.

For more if you want to do it yourself then you can look at the links at the bottom of this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand this to non-anchor tags, use jQuery.

```
$('div').click( function(){ 
   $(this).addClass("hovered');
} );
```